# Логин в Google Drive с помошью API Keys

Tags: python, google-drive

В google console создал API Keys. 
Написал скрипт который удаленно подключается к моему Google drive (Диск), и получает список папок. (Ну в общем скрипт много что делает, удаленно заливает файлы в мою папку, ищет нужную папку, создает папки, и т.д.) Но все это работает если подключаюсь через OAuth2WebServerFlow, однако так я делать могу только в случае разработки, так как в консоле мне выпадает первый рас ссылка по которой я перехожу и получаю код активизиции, подтверждаю его, и потом работает мой код спокойно сам.
Но на рабочем сервере, у меня нет возможности получать эту ссылку и ввести код активации, и программа просто замирает на этом шаге.

Выход - использовать API Keys. Как пишут в документации: “Всё очень просто, однако API Keys придется передавать каждый рас”. Я согласен его передавать каждый рас, но увы не выходит.

Но увы, ищу второй день и не могу найти ни единого примера работы с drive через API Keys.

Вот пример нерабочего куска кода, хотя по примерам и эксперементам я ну никакой ошибки тут не вижу.

```
#google key
API_key = "xxxxx"
#creating an instance of the class
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', developerKey = API_key)
#get a list of child folder in
children = drive_service.children().list(folderId='yyyyyyy', **param).execute()
```

Вываливает ошибку: HttpError 401 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json&key=xxxxx returned "Login Required"

Второй способ пробую:

```
f = open(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(service_email, key, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE, prn = email)
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http = http)
```

Ошибка тут: access_denied

Может кто-то в курсе что именно и как подсунуть google чтобы прошла авторизация по статическим данным?

Comment: Пришлите ссылку на документацию.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так заработало:

```
  f = file('privatekey.p12', 'rb')
  key = f.read()
  f.close()

  # Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
  # with the Credentials. Note that the first parameter, service_account_name,
  # is the Email address created for the Service account. It must be the email
  # address associated with the key that was created.
  credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
      '000000000000@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
      key,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks')
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  service = build("tasks", "v1", http=http)

  # List all the tasklists for the account.
  lists = service.tasklists().list().execute(http=http)
  pprint.pprint(lists)
```

Comment: Покажите весь код, причем, чтобы он работал для Google Drive API